Android studio to xcode
I am trying to run my android studio project onto Xcode. I am using kotlin multi platform , jet pack compose. I have a IOSApp.swift if that helps but when I open the IOSApp.xcodeproj it says “composed app” module cnat  be found
Loading the app on Xcode but says module can’t be found
